# Exception in queued task: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: javascript

The following code is suppose to join the text (without html) of the `content` attribute of many `Objects`:

```
var chapters = Chapters.find({
  bookId: this._id
}).fetch();
// => [Object, Object, Object]

var chapterContent = function() {
  var results = [];
  for (i = 0, len = chapters.length; i < len; i++) {
    var chapter = chapters[i];
    results.push(chapter.content.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ""));
  }
  return results;
});
// => ["srtrt", "fffff", "ggggg"] 


var chapterContentWords = chapterContent.join(" ");
// => srtrt fffff ggggg 

var chapterContentWordsNumber = chapterContentWords.match(/[\w-]+/g).length;
```

But in the last part (it's supposed to return the number of words), I get the following error:

> Exception in queued task: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of
>   null

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is supposed `chapters` to come from ? And are you aware that `match` may return `null` ?

Comment: Unable to reproduce, with the inputs you have shown

Comment: What is your last line of code `chapterContentWordsNumber = chapterContentWords.match(/[\w-]+/g).length;` supposed to return?

Comment: @chris97ong return the number of words. In this case 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of words, you could do something like this:

```
var chapterContentWordsNumber = chapterContentWords.split(" ").length;
```

Or simply:

```
var chapterContentWordsNumber = chapterContent.length;
```

Comment: I'm curious why there was an error when including `.match` ?